Sending Email With PHP not working or throwing errors. Tried debugging = 2
I'm not getting an error but I have commented out the image to see if that was the issue. It isn't and no emails are getting sent. Please help! I have copied the code almost verbatim from my other app where this works.
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load phpmailer
require '..\..\Portfolio\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\Exception.php';
require '..\..\Portfolio\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\PHPMailer.php';
require '..\..\Portfolio\vendor\phpmailer\phpmailer\src\SMTP.php';
require '..\..\Portfolio\vendor\autoload.php';

// Get values from form & send emails
if (isset($_POST["fname"]) && isset($_POST["lname"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["comment"]) && $wrongFile == false) {
    $fname = $_POST["fname"];
    $lname = $_POST["lname"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $comment = $_POST["comment"];

    try {
        // Send Email to Visitor
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Port = 25;
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Username = 'xxxxxx';
        $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx'; // gmail 2-factor app authenticator
        $mail->setFrom('mypinkapples@gmail.com');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $fname . ' ' . $lname);
        $mail->Subject = 'some text...';
        $mail->Body = 'additional email text...<br>';
        $mail->Body .= $comment . '<br>';
        $mail->Body .= '-' . $fname . ' ' . $lname . '<br>';
        //$mail->addAttachment(dirname(__FILE__) . $targetPath);
        $mail->send();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
    }

I've tried testing the data using echo and the data is correct. I've commented out the photo. I've changed around the file paths of the PHPMailer requirements until I found the right file path. I've changed the port numbers. I've tried $mail->SMTPDebug = 2 to find any debug errors which it threw none. I've looked in my spam folders in my email. I've read countless other StackOverflow questions and watched a few additional tutorials including a paid-for Udemy course. I've tried the "class" thing but I can't get it to work, it throws an error and I didn't need it in my other application where the email does work:
include_once('class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('class.smtp.php');

**Edit
My question is different than the one suggested because I have already changed those things over (port and ssl)

Try port 465 instead of 25?

make sure your using an apps password and port 465  Can't Send Email through PHP on localhost using Gmail account

class.phpmailer.php is from a very old version of PHPMailer; You don’t need that. If you are seeing nothing from debug level 2, it suggests you have a connection-level problem that might be reported better at level 3 or 4. ssl mode to port 25 definitely won’t work.
